# Is every number ring the localization of an order?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Given a number field $K$ and a subring $R \subseteq K$, does there exist a multiplicatively closed set $S \subseteq K^\times$ (where $S$ is possibly empty) and an order $A \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ so that $R = S^{-1}A$?

I'm ultimately trying to understand why $R/aR$ is finite for any $a \in R$.  This is not hard when $R$ is an order and by the exactness of localization, $R/aR$ is finite when $R$ is the localization of an order.  So if an arbitrary number ring $R$ is the localization of an order, then $R/aR$ is finite.

Comment: See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PF for a reason why $R/aR$ is finite

Comment: Thanks!  That answers the question which led to this question quite succinctly.